# Как из такого PHP массива Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 ) повторить число 1 - 1 раз, число 2 - 2 раза, 3 - 1 раз

Tags: php, алгоритм

На входе есть массив, например:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '2', '3'); //Входящий массив
```

Из него я получаю число повторений:

```
$result = array_count_values($array);    //считаем число повторений
```

Т.е. он стает вида `Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 )`

Как по правильному повторить число из ключа столько раз, сколько указано в значении?
На выходе чтобы получить из `Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 )`  такой?:

```
Array ('1','2','2','3')
```

На ум приходит только какой-то велосипед на подобии вытянуть все ключи через
`array_keys($result)` и крутонуть их значения в цикле fot столько то раз сколько указано значение... Hо как-то сильно сложно может есть лучшее решение?

Comment: Спасибо за правки)

Comment: то есть взять массива, чего то там покрутить, и получить исходный? в чем сутть?

Comment: Да, тупонул. Это середина задачи. Задумка такая что: 
$array = array('3', '3', '3'); //Входящий массив
$result = array_count_values($array);    //считаем число повторений
$unic = array_unique($array); //Оставляем уникальные
И потом я хотел вывести уникальные без изменений а число повторений сплюсовать между собой чтобы в итоге получить array('3', '33', '333');

Comment: Только просьба не минусовать вопрос за "Неполезность" или "Непонятность". Это реальная алготирмическая задача на формирование множества чисел. И ее успешно получилось решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 1];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, $value, $key)); // $result = [...$result, ...array_fill(0, $value, $key)];
}

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Взял на заметку array_fill и array_merge. Буду их изучать. Но я понял что я "Вася" и не верно задал вопрос и получил то что было на входе...
Изначально я пытаюсь сделать из массива $array = array('3', '3', '3'); 
Выходной вида array('3', '33', '333');
Пытаюсь их плюсовать нужное число раз и дошел до такого как в вопросе. Но в итоге я вернул то с чего начинал)

Comment: Тогда array_map и str_repeat помогут

Answer (score 0):

Ура! Заработало вот так (Спасибо Алексею за правильный путь и Ma3rX за правки)

Я правда не смог освоить как через array_map и str_repeat сделать...
Поэтому немного корявувато дописал цикл но выдает то что нужно:

```
$array = array(1, 1, 3, 3, 1); //Входящий массив
$result = array_count_values($array);    //считаем число повторений

//$allresult = []; //Пока без массива потом допишу
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $n = 0; //Сброс при каждом проходе чтобы запускался след цикл
        for ($value; $n <= $value; $n++) {
            echo str_repeat($key, $n) . ' ';
          }
    //$allresult = array_merge($allresult, array_fill(0, $value, $key));
}
```

Подаем на вход `array(1, 1, 3, 3, 1)`; Получаем: `1 11 111 3 33`

Подаем на вход `array(5, 5, 5, 5, 5)`; Получаем: `5 55 555 5555 55555`

Чудеса, но работает). А еще, если не тяжело, посоветуйте плиз какие-то может визуализации этих функций или учебники по PHP? С примерами, на каких то аналогиях, на котиках). А то встречаю новые функции и не совсем понимаю как их применить.